# I have the issue to Select User name two time in same mysql query... I want to select Received_by user name and Send_by user name

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Users:

```
UserID  |  UserName
----------------------
11       |  Allan 
15       |  Mark
16       |  Eric
```

My table name is Messages:

```
MessageID  |  Received_By  |  Sent_By
-------------------------------------
1            |  11              |  15
2            |  15              |  16
3            |  16              |  11`
```

So here I want to show both users name, message received_by and sent_by both user names I want to show.

my query:

```
SELECT
messages.id AS msg_id,
users.first_name,
messages.message,
messages.received_by_userid
messages.sent_by_userid
FROM messages
INNER JOIN users ON (messages.sent_by_id = users.id)
INNER JOIN users ON (messages.received_by_id = users.id)
```

I am getting only **received_by user name** not getting **sent_b user name** I need to show both names so plz help me with this, thanks

Comment: your query as shown will give an error, not "only received_by user name"

Answer (score 1):

You must use ALIASES for the tables to specify the table

```
SELECT
m.id AS msg_id,
m.message,
ur.UserName AS received_by,
us.UserName AS sent_by
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users us ON m.sent_by_id = us.id
INNER JOIN users ur ON m.received_by_id = u.id
```

Comment: thank you so much for your quick reply my issue has been solved.